# Can Akkusativ Objekt be written at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, grammatical-case, german-to-english

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen:

> Sie hängt die Hose an den Haken
>
> Die Hose hängt sie an den Haken.

Welcher Satz  ist richtig und warum?

Comment: Beide Sätze sind prinzipiell richtig. Im zweiten Fall wird "die Hose" besonders betont: sie hängt _die Hose_, und nicht etwa das Sakko, auf den Haken. Im Normalfall wird man die erste Variante wählen.

Comment: @ Ingmar: you should make your comment an answer, I think it fully covers the question

Answer (score 3):

Im deutschen Aussagesatz kann man prinzipiell alle Satzglieder bis auf den Kern des Prädikats (hier: *hängt*) vertauschen. Die folgenden Sätze sind alle richtig:

> **Sie** hängt die Hose *an den Haken*.
>
> **Die Hose** hängt sie *an den Haken*.
>
> **An den Haken** hängt sie *die Hose*.

Diese Sätze unterscheiden sich nur durch die Hervorhebung. Das erste Satzglied ist **besonders hervorgehoben**, das letzte *hervorgehoben*. Und das ist bereits ganz ohne zusätzliche Betonung beim Sprechen der Fall.

Es gibt noch drei weitere Varianten. Diese klingen schlecht bis falsch. Der Vollständigkeit halber führe ich sie auf:

> <s>Sie hängt an den Haken die Hose.</s>
>
> <s>Die Hose hängt an den Haken sie.</s>

Adverbiale Bestimmungen des Ortes sollten den anderen Objekten vorangehen oder folgen anstatt sich zwischen Subjekt und Objekt zu mogeln.

> <s>An den Haken hängt die Hose sie.</s>
>
> An den Haken hängt die Hose *Tante Elli*.
>
> An den Haken hängt die Hose *nur sie*.

Einsame Personalpronomen am Ende eines Satzes klingen schlecht. Das kann man heilen, indem man einen Namen einsetzt oder ein Adverb oder Partikel voranstellt.

Comment: *Sie hängt an **den** Haken die Hose und an **den** Haken die Jacke* klingt für mich nach einem ganz normalen Satz, der lediglich die Betonung anders legt. Auch *Sie hängt an den **Haken** die Hose (und nicht auf den Bügel)* ist durchaus gängig.

Comment: Da musst du aber überbetonen. *An **den** Haken hängt sie die Hose und an **den** Haken die Jacke.* klingt immer noch natürlicher.

Comment: Ohne Gestik (auf den einen speziellen Haken zeigen) und ohne die natürliche Betonung im gesprochenen Satz wäre hier die Variante *An **diesen** Haken hängt sie die Hose und an **jenen** (Haken) die Jacke* sinnvoller

Comment: @Janka Mag sein, aber dennoch finde ich die andere Wortstellung nicht ungewöhnlicher.